# Is it possible to construct a pseudo-inverse of a 4-order tensor?

Tags: tensors, pseudoinverse

I am new here, and a physicist, so excuse me in case I do not use the right jargon but I think this is a question for the math community:

In 1-D, I have a signal, represented by a vector **v** of dimension *n*, that is "deformed" by a matrix **A** (*m,n*) to give **w** (*m*): 
$$ \mathbf{w} = A\mathbf{v}
$$

In my experiment I measure **w** and I know **A**, so to estimate **v** I do
$$ \mathbf{v'} = A^+\mathbf{w}
$$
$A^+$ being the (Moore-Penrose)pseudo-inverse. **A** has independent rows, $m<n$, $A^+$ is right-inverse (these statements are equivalent, right?).

When I simulate the experiment **v'** gives a reasonable estimate of **v**. I interpret $\mathbf{v'}=A^+A\mathbf{v}$ as losing information in $A$ and a kind of interpolation in $A^+$.

Now I would like to do the same thing, but where my signal is a 2-D image, and the deformation is described by a 4-th order tensor. So the image "**v**" now has dimensions (*n,n*), the measurement **w** (*m,m*) and thus **A** has now become a tensor of dimensions (*m,m,n,n*).

Is there such a thing as a pseudoinverse for a 4-th order tensor? If not, why not?

(If yes, a link to a (python-)code would be much appreciated)

Comment: I would avoid that problem by treating the 2D $w\times h$ image as a 1D $w\cdot h$ vector.

Comment: Oh right, that's a nice and simple solution, should've thought of that.. But I didn't, so thank you very much!